# Visual Basic Tic Tac Toe error

Tags: visual-studio-2010

hey everyone i'm trying to create ttt and it works but when i do a test run and i make a player win, the last character doesn't show. if it's supposed to be 3 X's or O's aligned, the computer will recognize the winning move and declare a winner but btnclicked.text s still = nothing. here's my code, i have no idea how to fix it and because of that, the if statements that would recognize a draw and produce an output an't be evaluated.

`Private Sub btnMoveMade_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles _
        btn00.Click, btn01.Click, btn02.Click, btn10.Click, btn11.Click, btn12.Click, btn20.Click,
        btn21.Click, btn22.Click
        Dim btnSquareClicked As Button = sender
        Dim player1 As String = Me.txtName1.Text
        Dim player2 As String = Me.txtname2.Text
        Static chrTTT(2, 2) As Char
        Static player As String = "X"
        If btnSquareClicked.Text <> Nothing Then
            MessageBox.Show("Invalid Move.")
        Else
            Dim index As String
            index = btnSquareClicked.Tag
            Dim x As Integer = Val(index.Chars(0))
            Dim y As Integer = Val(index.Chars(1))
            Call StoreMove(x, y, player, chrTTT)
            If IsWinner(chrTTT) Then
                player = player1
                MessageBox.Show(player & "!, Congratulations, You Won!")
                btnNewGame.Visible = True
            ElseIf IsWinner2(chrTTT) Then
                player = player2
                MessageBox.Show(player & "!, Congratulations, You won!")
                btnNewGame.Visible = True
            ElseIf btn00.Text <> Nothing And btn01.Text <> Nothing And btn02.Text <> Nothing And btn10.Text <> Nothing And btn11.Text <> Nothing _
                And btn12.Text <> Nothing And btn20.Text <> Nothing And btn21.Text <> Nothing _
                And btn22.Text <> Nothing And IsWinner(chrTTT) = False And IsWinner2(chrTTT) = False Then
                MessageBox.Show("Aww, it's a draw")
            Else
                If player = "X" Then
                    player = "O"
                    btnSquareClicked.Text = "X"
                Else
                    player = "X"
                    btnSquareClicked.Text = "O"
                End If
            End If
        End If
    End Sub
    Sub StoreMove(ByVal x As Integer, ByVal y As Integer, ByVal player As Char, ByRef TTT(,) As Char)
        TTT(x, y) = player
    End Sub
    Function IsWinner(ByRef TTT(,) As Char) As Boolean
        For row As Integer = 0 To 2
            If TTT(row, 0) = TTT(row, 1) And TTT(row, 1) = TTT(row, 2) And TTT(row, 0) = "X" Then
                Return True
            End If
        Next row
        For col As Integer = 0 To 2
            If TTT(0, col) = TTT(1, col) And TTT(1, col) = TTT(2, col) And TTT(0, col) = "X" Then
                Return True
            End If
        Next col
        If TTT(0, 0) = TTT(1, 1) And TTT(1, 1) = TTT(2, 2) And TTT(0, 0) = "X" Then
            Return True
        End If
        If TTT(0, 2) = TTT(1, 1) And TTT(1, 1) = TTT(2, 0) And TTT(0, 2) = "X" Then
            Return True
        End If
        Dim movesLeft As Boolean = False
        For row As Integer = 0 To 2
            For col As Integer = 0 To 2
                If TTT(row, col) = Nothing Then
                    movesLeft = True
                End If
            Next col
        Next row
        If Not movesLeft Then
            Return True
        End If
        Return False
    End Function
    Function IsWinner2(ByRef TTT(,) As Char) As Boolean
        For row As Integer = 0 To 2
            If TTT(row, 0) = TTT(row, 1) And TTT(row, 1) = TTT(row, 2) And TTT(row, 0) = "O" Then
                Return True
            End If
        Next row
        For col As Integer = 0 To 2
            If TTT(0, col) = TTT(1, col) And TTT(1, col) = TTT(2, col) And TTT(0, col) = "O" Then
                Return True
            End If
        Next col
        If TTT(0, 0) = TTT(1, 1) And TTT(1, 1) = TTT(2, 2) And TTT(0, 0) = "O" Then
            Return True
        End If
        If TTT(0, 2) = TTT(1, 1) And TTT(1, 1) = TTT(2, 0) And TTT(0, 2) = "O" Then
            Return True
        End If
        Dim movesLeft As Boolean = False
        For row As Integer = 0 To 2
            For col As Integer = 0 To 2
                If TTT(row, col) = Nothing Then
                    movesLeft = True
                End If
            Next col
        Next row
        If Not movesLeft Then
            Return True
        End If
        Return False
    End Function
End Class`

Comment: Then obviously you have flawed logic in your `IsWinner()` and/or `IsWinner2()` functions.  I'd look there first.  Those two functions could easily be one function by the way.

Comment: They were, i changed them for the sake of the the player names/ me.txtnames

Answer (score 0):

Set the Button Text **before** you do anything else:

```
    If btnSquareClicked.Text <> Nothing Then
        MessageBox.Show("Invalid Move.")
    Else
        btnSquareClicked.Text = player

        ' ... rest of the code ...

    End If
```

Comment: thanks a lot, i just tried it and it worked, but the the message box that is suppose to show when it's a draw till doesn't come up, instead it still tells me that one of the players won

ElseIf btn00.Text <> Nothing And btn01.Text <> Nothing And btn02.Text <> Nothing And btn10.Text <> Nothing And btn11.Text <> Nothing _
                And btn12.Text <> Nothing And btn20.Text <> Nothing And btn21.Text <> Nothing _
                And btn22.Text <> Nothing And IsWinner(chrTTT) = False And IsWinner2(chrTTT) = False Then
                MessageBox.Show("Aww, it's a draw")

code to get a draw

Answer (score 0):

thanks a lot, i just tried it and it worked, but the the message box that is suppose to show when it's a draw till doesn't come up, instead it still tells me that one of the players won

`ElseIf btn00.Text <> Nothing And btn01.Text <> Nothing And btn02.Text <> Nothing And btn10.Text <> Nothing And btn11.Text <> Nothing _
                And btn12.Text <> Nothing And btn20.Text <> Nothing And btn21.Text <> Nothing _
                And btn22.Text <> Nothing And IsWinner(chrTTT) = False And IsWinner2(chrTTT) = False Then
                MessageBox.Show("Aww, it's a draw")`

that's the section dedicated to checking for a draw.